# Why does running a simple three.js scene eventually hang in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, node-webkit

I created the simple cube [as explained in the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) but i stumbled upon a really annoying problem. After a while the cube stops spinning and it seems the apps hangs. Why does it hang? It seems to appear randomly. [I recorded the problem and put it on youtube](http://youtu.be/Wt-iyx4nJPY).

I have a high end game PC.

The code is very simple:

```
// create a WebGL renderer, camera and scene
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var scene    = new THREE.Scene();

// Add the camera to the scene
scene.add(camera);

// The camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
camera.position.z = 5;

// Start the renderer
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Attach the renderer-supplied DOM element 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Resize canvas when window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}, false);

// Add test cube
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00 });
var cube     = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// Add test cube to scene
scene.add(cube);

// Render
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.05;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

Comment: Are you running this in node-webkit? why have you included that tag?

Comment: Yes it is running in node-webkit (see youtube video)

Comment: sounds like you should file a bug on node-webkit

Answer (score 0):

add this to your **package.json**

```
"chromium-args": "--disable-threaded-compositing"﻿
```